# Exibir String completa no modal

Tags: javascript, java, primefaces, wildfly

estou usando Java,JPA, Wildfly e Primefaces.Eu tenho uma tabela que exibe um texto,mas esse texto esta sendo cortado na exibição pelo tamano da tabela.Resolvi criar um boão que chama um modal para exibir o texto completo.Cada linha da tabela tem o seu botão para exibir o seu detalhe.
O problema é que em qualquer botão que eu aciono ele me mostra a ultima string, o ultimo texto.
Segue o código em XHTML da coluna:

```html
 <p:column headerText="Detalhes">
       <p:commandButton value="Visualizar detalhes" type="button"
        onclick="PF('dlg1').show();" update="idDescricao" />
       <p:dialog header="Modal Detalhes" widgetVar="dlg1" minHeight="40"
        width="700" id="idDescricao">
         <p:outputPanel id="multiCarDetail" style="text-align:center;">
           <ui:repeat value="#{cadastroMB.listaCadastro}"  var="cad">
        <h:outputText value="#{cad.descricao}" />
        </ui:repeat>
        </p:outputPanel>
       </p:dialog>
      </p:column>
```

A Imagem abaixo mostra que acionei o segundo botão mas esta me exibindo a da primeira linha
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

O problema esta que no seu teste não existe espaço entre as palavras "Teste", o que a torna uma palavra muito grande. 
O PrimeFaces quebra a linha como é o caso da primeira linha da imagem. 
Experimente dar espaços entre as palavras isso tornará o teste mais realista.

Comment: Exatamente, antes eu utilizava um textArea, resolvi mudar para o painel de edição, funcionou normalmente pq digiando na mão funciona só que eu esava copiando e colando um texto, erro bobo mas que nao prestava atenção na hora de desenvolver, Obrigado Marcelo